# Android getBackgroundResource from string

Tags: android, image, button

Ok guys, let's say i have a *String k = "image1";* and there is a picture in my drawable folder with name image1.png for example. How i can change a button image getting the name of the image from that string? Let's say the button name is button1, then  *button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.image1);* could work, but i want something like *button1.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.k);* and k get the value "image1", so for example i can pick the image name from a database. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily achieved by calling

```
int resID = getContext().getResources().getIdentifier("imageName", "drawable", "yourPackageName");
```

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)

Comment: +1 although `getContext()` isn't necessary when calling `getResources()` in an `Activity`.

Comment: That's right, I just wanted to be sure that that snipped works even outside an activity.

Comment: so i tried int resID = getResources().getIdentifier("image1", null, null); and then button1.setBackgroundResource(resID); and it didn't work maybe i missing something?

Comment: solved, i had to replace first null with "drawable" and second null with package name thank you! ;)